# Private integer not updating

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, var, mousedown

Trying to write a script that's on several different objects where on mouseclick, 1 is added to a defined variable which then prints out. Currently when I click the objects, 1 is always printed.

```
#pragma strict
import UnityEngine.UI;

var theImage:UnityEngine.UI.Image; 
var theSprite:Sprite; //The image you want to drag in the inspector
private var clickCount = 0;

function OnMouseDown () {
  theImage.sprite = theSprite;
  clickCount++;
  Debug.Log(clickCount);
}
```

Here's my script. It also changes a GUI sprite. Seems like an easy fix, not sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Is clickCount a variable local to the class? If so, it would show 1 every time you clicked a new object, but should increment if you click the same object multiple times.

Comment: You can make clickCount a static variable. http://docs.unity3d.com/401/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Member_Variables_26_Global_Variables.html

Comment: show full code plz